# HOGDescriptor in opencv3 C++14

Tags: c++, opencv, c++14, opencv3.0

I am trying to migrate a C++ code from C++11 opencv2 to C++14 opencv3.

The original syntax is:

```
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>

setSVM(128, 64, cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor::getPeopleDetector64x128(), 0.0);
```

But the gpu.hpp header file has been removed, however I still didn't manage to find the correct syntax and namespace for the **HOGDescriptor**. I am appreciated your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>

// Returns coefficients of the classifier trained for people detection (for 64x128 windows).
cv::HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector();
```

[Document](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html)